# SpresenseのGNSSアドオンボードでパッシブアンテナは使えますでしょうか？

Tags: spresense

SpresenseのGNSSアドオンボードにできるだけ小型の外部アンテナを接続して、GNSSトラッカーを作成しようと思ってます。
動作確認済みのアンテナリストを見ると、すべてアクティブアンテナのようなのですが、パッシブアンテナでも動作しますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

GNSS Add-on ボードは、アクティブアンテナの使用を前提としており、
LNAを搭載していないため、パッシブアンテナを使用することができません。
[動作確認済みアンテナリスト](https://developer.sony.com/ja/spresense/specifications/confirmed-antenna-list/)に記載のあるアクティブアンテナをご使用いただくようお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

実際に使用したアンテナのメーカー、型番などの記載ありませんが、アクティブでもパッシブでも使えると記載があります。
[gnssの使用方法](https://developer.sony.com/ja/spresense/development-guides/hw_docs_ja.html#_gnss%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

Comment: ご紹介のリンクと説明はメインボード上のGNSSチップ/回路の説明でしょう。質問の方はL1帯/L5帯を両方使うアドオンボードを使いたいのだと思われます。[IoT向けスマートセンシングプロセッサ搭載ボード 「SPRESENSE(TM)」の デュアルバンド測位高精度GNSSアドオンボードを商品化](https://www.atpress.ne.jp/news/362588), [デュアルバンド測位で業界最小※1の消費電力を実現IoT・ウェアラブル機器向け高精度GNSS受信LSIを商品化](https://www.sony.com/ja/SonyInfo/News/Press/202008/20-069/) そのアドオンボードあるいは使用しているチップでパッシブアンテナが使えるかどうか・使えるとしても精度が出るかどうかでしょうか。

Comment: oh...add-on boardの方か...しっかり読めてませんでしたね。申し訳ないです。
同じ過ちを繰り返す人が居ないように、解答はこのままにしておきます...

Answer (score 0):

新しいGNSSのaddon基板使っています。感想ですが、衛星の感度低くてもメイン基板搭載の内蔵GPSよりは捕捉しやすい印象があります。
試しに、手持ちの昔から使っているパッシブアンテナをつないで家の窓側に向けてCold測位させてみましたが、測位することはできました（L5信号も見れました）。ですので受かるケースはあると思います。ただし、アクティブアンテナと切り替えて同じ衛星のCN差でみたところで、あくまでもその時の環境条件での参考例ですが、約数dB（4、5～）は違うようです。どういう環境での使用を目指しているか次第にはなると思いますが、屋外では使えるかもしれません。あくまでも自己責任でお願いします。
さらに、利用のレベルによっては以下のところの考慮も必要になると思います。
・使いたい衛星周波数帯域を持つアンテナを選ぶ。
・アンテナへの電力供給遮断用にDCカッターをつける。